# How do i display category images and also link them to items under that category am using shoppe rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display category images with its respective link to items under that category in shoppe am using rails 4 and what i have tried so far gives me :
Name Error or No method error  here's what my code looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8 col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-inline">   
    <% Shoppe::ProductCategory.all.each do %>

      <div class="portfolio-item ">
        <div class="portfolio-img">
          <%= image_tag @product_category, class: "port-item" %>
            <div class="portfolio-img-hover">
              <link_to
            </div> <!-- /.portfolio-img-hover -->
        </div> <!-- /.portfolio-img -->
      <div class="portfolio-item-details">
        <div class="portfolio-item-name">
          </small>
    <% end %>
```

I created a productscategory controller but its empty

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Also your code is incomplete. Please include the full code.

Comment: thanks my exact error says : nomethod error for the word default_image_path. My real problem is displaying the category pictures in that products categories page please i dont even know what to do again especially how to get the categories images path

Comment: i have gone through nifty attachments to know if i can get the image path for the category image and the link to products path through the categories . although i do think that shoppe already made associations for the linking